# Is there a more elegant way to add usercontrols to a list?

Tags: asp.net, optimization, user-controls

I have 10 custom usercontrol's with ID's usercontrol1, usercontrol2, usercontrol3......usercontrol10.

I want to add all these usercontrols to a List "allusercontrol". I do this with brute force like this

```
allusercontrol.Add(usercontrol1);
allusercontrol.Add(usercontrol2);
allusercontrol.Add(usercontrol3);
.
.
.
.
.
```

Is there a more elegant and easy way of doing this trivial task? You do see that the usercontrols ID's are a part of a series `"usercontrol"+an int`

Comment: Don't name your controls in such an anonymous way. What is more prone to errors: `Button1,Button2,Button2` or `BtnInsert,BtnUpdate,BtnDelet`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Updated my question for user control

Comment: Where are these usercontrols coming from? Are they already on an aspx page?

Comment: Yes they are already in the aspx page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against this approach since it's prone to errors. What if you want to rename them, what if you'll forget about this and add other controls with name `ButtonX` that should not be in this list?

Instead i would collect them in a container control like `Panel`.
Then you can use `LINQ` to find the relevant `Buttons`:

```
var myButtons = myPanel.Controls.OfType<Button>();
```

`Enumerable.OfType` will filter and cast the controls accordingly. If you want to filter them more, you could use `Enumerable.Where`, for example:

```
var myButtons = myPanel.Controls
                       .OfType<Button>()
                       .Where(btn => btn.ID.ToLower().StartsWith("button"));
```

Now you can iterate those `Buttons`, for example:

```
foreach(Button btn in myButtons)
{
    // do something amazing
}
```

Or you can just call `ToList()` to get a `List<Button>` (the core of your question):

```
List<Button> allbuttons = myButtons.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that's a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
List<UserControl> controls = new List<UserControl>
{
    usercontrol1,
    usercontrol2,
    usercontrol3
};
```

Comment: There would still be a lot of code, consider a scenario of 100 usercontrols.

Comment: Ok, Try with this code YourContainer.Controls.OfType<UserControl>();

Answer (score 0):

Use Control.ControlCollection.AddRange - look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.addrange.aspx)